# Oracle error occurred, but error message could not be retrieved from Oracle

Tags: delphi, oracle10g, delphi-2006

There is a delphi application in which I am trying to connect to Oracle database Using provider MSDAORA.1 but problem is coming in connecting. Oracle error message which is coming is "Oracle error occurred, but error message could not be retrieved from Oracle"

I am able to connect to database with Oracle10g client.

```
Connection String: Provider=MSDAORA.1;
User ID=murat;
Password = murat;
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp) (HOST= INGPSP)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=INGPSP)));
Persist Security Info=False;
```

Please provide your expert opinion what can be the reason of this?

Comment: Did you try with the Oracle OleDB provider? It is much more updated than the Microsoft's one, which is officialy deprecated. You should better use a direct connection to Oracle, without ADO/OleDB - see for instance http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=549 or http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/07/09/SynDBOracle%3A-Open-Source-native-Oracle-access

Answer (score 2):

The service name seems to be lacking in your address.

Set a tnsnames.ora file, and use the entry as data source instead of the data_source parameter you set. Follow the steps available [on the faq](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora).

Or use use connection strings like '//host[:port]/[service_name]' for your data source: //INGPSP:1521/ServiceName

For Oracle, both Microsoft and Oracle OleDB providers are known to have issue with BLOBs. If you can, use another mean of connection.

Answer (score 0):

What I see that is strange is that your HOST and SID are the same.  The HOST is the name of the machine on your network and the SID is the database instance on that machine.  I created the following ConnectionString for the PRD3 database on machine DB19 (there are multiple databases on DB19) on our network.  I was able to connect to the database successfully with real User ID and Password.

```
Provider=MSDAORA.1;
Password=123456;
User ID=abc;
Data Source="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=db19)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=prd3)))";
Persist Security Info=True
```

Normally the Data Source I use is the database name as defined in TNSNAMES.ORA.  It is a lot less to type (fewer potential errors) and can be changed to another database without recompiling the program (such as switching between a development database and production database).